# Как разбить код на потоки?

Tags: c#

Из-за большого кол-ва кода, у меня зависает форма (пишу на winforms). Я решил разбить на потоки, но не получается. Привожу  часть кода.

```
public Form1()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory+ "/Images/face.gif");
            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory+ "/Images/sss.gif");

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(Encrypt); //именно здесь есть недопонимание
            thread1.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;    
            thread1.Start();                
        }

string Encrypt(string text)
        {            
            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                binary.Append(Convert.ToString(text[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
            }
            return binary.ToString();
        }
```

К слову, я вообще не понимаю, как все правильно сделать. Форма зависает и не двигается. 
Думал, что из-за гиф форма перегружается, но нет.

Как я понял, не получается использовать эту строку:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(Encrypt);
```

Из-за типа string в функции Encrypt.

Encrypt потом используется здесь:

```
public string Venom()
        { 
            return Encrypt(textBox1.Text);
        }

        public string Papanya()
        { //KEY 2
            return Encrypt(textBox3.Text);
        }
```

А потом здесь:

```
 static char GetChar(string Papanya, ref int lastIndex)
        {
            if (++lastIndex >= Papanya.Length)
                lastIndex = 0;
            return Papanya[lastIndex];
        }


public static string PairConcat(string Encrypt, string venom)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < venom.Length; i++)
            {
                result.Append(venom[i]);
                result.Append(GetNextChar(Encrypt, ref index));
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: метод научного тыка тут мало поможет, необходима отладка

Comment: Куда должно попасть то, что возвращает метод `Encrypt`, и откуда возьмется его параметр `text`?

Comment: Igor, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: По-моему, давать worker-thread'у высший приоритет - не лучшая идея. Он будет блокировать поток с UI и пользователь увидит зависание.

Comment: У вас действительно в реальном коде есть имена `Venom` и `Papanya`? Что такие имена дадут понять? А также `textBox1`, `textBox3`.

Comment: Для начала, разбейте вопрос на два: как передать в поток параметр и как использовать поток, чтобы не зависал GUI.